# unable to mount linux partiton - can't read super block

Tags: filesystems

fdisk-l

```
/dev/sda1               1           3       24066   83  Linux
/dev/sda2              26        1300    10241437+  83  Linux
/dev/sda3            1301       60801   477941782+   5  Extended
/dev/sda5            1301        1338      305203+  82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6            1339       60801   477636516   83  Linux
```

The offending partiton is sda6. Here's the output when I tried to search for an alternative superblock

```
sudo dumpe2fs /dev/sda6 | grep superblock
dumpe2fs 1.41.11 (14-Mar-2010)
dumpe2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda6
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

Any chance of rescuing this partition I don't want to have reinstall debian. It's a pain since the hdd is from a NAS

```
sudo file -s /dev/sda6
/dev/sda6: SGI XFS filesystem data (blksz 4096, inosz 256, v2 dirs)
```

By the way according to apt-get I already have xfsprogs installed

Comment: Could you add the output of `sudo file -s /dev/sda6` to your question?

Comment: Have you already tried running xfs_repair ?

Comment: `dump2efs` is used for `ext*` filesystems. Try something like `sudo mount -t xfs /dev/sda6 /mnt`.